# Effect of measurement error on posterior probability

Tags: bayesian, bias, measurement-error

If the predictor $X$ in a simple linear regression $Y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} X + \epsilon$ is measured with error, the OLS estimator for the predictor's coefficient will be [biased towards zero](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/479276). What is the corresponding effect on the posterior of $\beta_1$ in a Bayesian setup? Is there (only?) an analog effect on the MAP being biased towards zero, or is the "width" of the posterior also affected?

Comment: Since the posterior is a combination of the prior and the "wrong" likelihood, my intuition suggests that the entire posterior will be affected. Since Bayesian estimators are, already without measurement error, not unbiased in general, there is no reason to suppose they will not be here, either. They could however still be biased away from zero if the prior has sufficiently large prior mean.

Comment: I also assume that the effect on the _mean_ of the (marginal) posterior $p(\beta_{1}|{X,Y})$ is identical to the attenuation bias for $\hat{\beta}_{1}^{(OLS)}$. But what, if any, is the effect on the "rest" of the posterior distribution?

Comment: I would expect the entire distribution to be somewhat shifted so as to affect the mean in the discussed way. But this is indeed a conjecture only as it stands.

Comment: Sure, if the mean shifts so does the entire distribution. But how (if at all) are the variance (or higher moments) affected?

Comment: The Bayesian approach would be to model the measurement error. [Statistical Rethinking](https://xcelab.net/rm/statistical-rethinking/) has a section on this; see Chapter 15.

Comment: I'm aware. There's an even more detailed treatment on the _correction_ or proper modelling of measurement error in [Carroll et al.](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/chapters/mono/10.1201/9781420010138-15/), but for some reason neither of those two nor any other book that I know of discusses the affect of _neglected_ measurement error on the posterior.